# Undefinded Signs in WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I've bound a collection to a datagrid. An in the header I have on the left and the right side a sign i can't imagine.

[See this picture, to understand what I mean](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-20473669/WPF_DataGrid.jpg.html)

What can it be, and how can I remove them. Here's the Style for the datagrid.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: First off.. try setting the `HeadersVisibility` to `True` instead of `Column`

Comment: There exists no optin True and all other options didn't help.

Comment: Problem solved: In the header of the Datagrid is something what has the Border-Property. In my Style I had given a style for all borders. Noe I have changed this and the border in the datagrid is away.